# Is it safe to mark a binding to a SwiftUI @State as `@unchecked Sendable`?

Tags: swift, swiftui, concurrency

I have a type containing a binding to a SwiftUI `@State` and I want to make it `Sendable`. But I get a warning:

```swift
struct MyType: Sendable {
    // Warning: Stored property 'binding' of 'Sendable'-conforming struct 'MyType' has non-sendable type 'Binding<Bool>'
    var binding: Binding<Bool> // Guaranteed to be coming from a @State
}
```

Since `@State` is [thread safe](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state), is it safe to do this?:

```swift
struct MyType: @unchecked Sendable {
    var binding: Binding<Bool> // Guaranteed to be coming from a @State
}
```

I'm not sure about this

## Edit: Some Context

I wanted to boil down the problem as much as possible, but here's the full context:

I'm trying to build a property wrapper that lets you trigger a view state by calling an `async` method on it (for example to `await` the results of a confirmation dialog view).

To do that, the property wrapper is a `DynamicProperty` and contains a private state `@State var isActive: Bool` that is completely invisible to the outside. It is only exposed in a special wrapper view that lets you control a view presentation (a sheet, alert or whatever).

From the outside, you just call a special `async` method, which suspends the current Task and internally stores a `CheckedContinuation`. Then, the view state will be set to `true` and the connected view is presented. That view has access to the stored continuation and can resume it with a result. Once that happens, the Task is resumed and the caller receives the result.

You can find the full implementation here:
https://github.com/SwiftedMind/Puddles/blob/main/Sources/Puddles/Navigation/Patterns/Queryable/Queryable.swift

And this is the wrapper view that exposes the view state and the continuation:
https://github.com/SwiftedMind/Puddles/blob/main/Sources/Puddles/Navigation/Patterns/Queryable/QueryControlled.swift

To do all that, I need to pass around `Binding`s and I'm getting Concurrency warnings (when the checker is set to "Complete") because `Binding` is not sendable.

The thing is: Everything seems to be working just fine, but I'm not sure if it's correct and always safe.

Comment: No it isn’t, we are not privy to the inner workings. There is no way for you to ensure that it is safe. There is also no reason to “Send” a binding. They only work in SwiftUI views so putting it in a regular struct isn’t advisable.

Comment: No.  Binding is simply a combination of get and set closures so could never be sendable.

Comment: Yeah, that's why, in general, `Binding` cannot be Sendable. But I'm talking about this special case where I absolutely can guarantee, that the setter changes a `@State`, which itself is sendable and thread safe. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: Perhaps you can step back and edit your question to describe what broader problem you are trying to solve…

Comment: @Rob I've updated the question and provided context as well as the full implementation of what I'm talking about :)